# Issues accessing values in a Javascript map, possible issue with function execution order

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, maps

I'm working on a Twilio video application and I am having issues accessing remote participant video/audio tracks which are delivered via a map. Playing around with dev tools has shown me that the values I need ought to be accessible by the methods I'm using, but it isn't seeming to work. 
The code for the setting up the room:

```
function connectVid(){
Twilio.Video.connect(localStorage.vidToken, {
    audio: true,
    video: {width: 520}
}).then(function(room){
    window.room = room;
    console.log('Connected to Room: ', room.name);
    Twilio.Video.createLocalTracks().then(function(localTracks) {
        console.log('Creating tracks in Room: ');
        console.log(room);
        console.log('Got default audio and video tracks: ', localTracks);
        var localParticipant = room.localParticipant;
        trackArray = localTracks;
        console.log(trackArray);
        console.log('Connected to the Room as localParticipant "%s"', localParticipant.identity);
        var localMediaContainer = document.getElementById('lstream');
        localTracks.forEach(function(track) {
            localMediaContainer.appendChild(track.attach());
        });
    })
}).then(function(room){
    attachRemoteParticipant();
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err.message);
    if(err.code === 20104) {
        getVidToken();
    };
})
};
```

The attachRemoteParticipant(); code:

```
function attachRemoteParticipant() {
room.participants.forEach(function(participant) {
    console.log('Participant "%s" is connected to the Room', participant.identity);
    var remoteContainer = document.getElementById('rstream');
    var remoteTracks = Array.from(participant.tracks.values());
    console.log("Remote Tracks COMING:");
    console.log(remoteTracks);
    remoteTracks.forEach(function(track){
        console.log('In Remote 4 each');
        console.log(track); 
        remoteContainer.appendChild(track.attach());
    }); 
});
};
```

I've tried including the attachRemoteParticipant function un-abstracted within the connectVid() code, at the end of the first then(function(...){...}) as a call outside connectVid which should occur afterwards like so:

```
$('#new-twilio-video').click(function(){
    if(localStorage.vidToken == undefined) {
        getVidToken();
        // attachRemoteParticipant();
    } else {
        connectVid();
        // attachRemoteParticipant();
    }
    addVidModal();
});
```

Uncommented of course. What gets logged with `console.log('Participant "%s" is connected to the Room', participant.identity);` is correct, but `console.log(remoteTracks);` produces an empty array. HOWEVER if I use Dev Tools to run `room.participants.forEach(function(participant) {console.log(Array.from(participant.tracks.values());})` I receive exactly what I want.
I presume the issue has to do with the `Array.from(...)` call occurring before the values are ready to be extracted, hence my attempts to prevent early execution, but I could be wrong. Any suggestions would be appreciated.
EDIT: The dev tools provides the array I want but also an `undefined` as the second result. Would that cause an issue?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I had to call my methods accessing the map values after a setTimeout. Somehow the values that appear in the console.log are not accessible until later. I couldn't figure out a graceful way to do it (using plain promises and async / await didn't work) but good ol' setTimeout did the trick.